# Solution to slow transfer of files from PC to USB

Tags: usb, files, transfer, fat32

First of all, my apologies: I've seen a tons of forums related to this topic, but **nowhere did I see a solution to this problem**.

I've switched to Linux only recently and my biggest issue about it is the PC to USB transfer speed. While transferring the files, I see the bar getting stuck at random times and then filling up again after some time. This reflects on speed.

*So, any suggestion?*

Comment: check if `usbmount` is installed, if so remove it.

Comment: usbmount isn't installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you mention it: No one ever asked what the ***solution* to the slow USB speed** is.  Everyone just wants to know *why*...

### Solution:

**Don't buy don't buy [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) USB sticks, buy [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) ones!**

### Why?

[SLC USB sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) are cheap and you get what you pay for: [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) ones are 2-8 times faster (depending on the technology of your original SLC), last 2-8 times longer (again: compared you your *Crap Inc Ⓡ Mega! Hyper! USB stick*)  *However, they're 2-3 times more expensive and are generally not on stock if you walk into any random corner-store.*

Basically: these are mini-SSD drives in a USB form factor.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: Well, ok, I can accept this answer, but still, it bothers me that on Windows, with the same flash drive, i got 2 times the speed than on Linux.

Nevertheless, thank you for your time :)

Comment: Aha!  That's new information!  :-) I upvoted your question, so you should have a bit more rep now too!  What's the format of that particular USB stick?

Comment: Thank you! :) The filesystem is fat32. I messed a bit with fstab: 

# USB flash drive 
/dev/sdc1       /mnt/sdc1       vfat    user,async,noauto    0 0

I tried using async instead of flush, and I'm getting pretty good results to, average write speed to Kingston Data Traveler 16GB is 11MB/s, which I think is pretty good :) 

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Not bad...  If you reformat it regularly, nothing to add!  ;)  Success!

Comment: Will do, thank you for your time and compliments! :)

Comment: I should by one of this things :)